# Configuring an Angular Animation with component input parameters?

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript, angular-animations

I'd like to be able to provide an `@Input` parameter for the timing of the animation in [this circle progress demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-uzxhcg?file=src%2Fsvg-circle.component.ts,src%2Fmain.template.html,src%2Fsvg-circle.component.svg).

However the animation is configured inside the `@Component` decorator and if I understand correctly that code does not have access to the components runtime state.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'el-circle-progress',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  templateUrl: `./svg-circle.component.svg`,
  styleUrls: ['./svg-circle.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  animations: [
    trigger('animateStroke', [
      state(
        '*',
        style({
          'stroke-dashoffset': '*',
        })
      ),
      transition('*<=>*', animate('3s linear')),
    ]),
  ],
})
```

Is there a way to configure dynamic animation parameters?

Currently the transition is configured like this:

```
transition('*<=>*', animate('3s linear')),
```

And I'd like to make the `3s` dynamic ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was playing around a bit in your stackblitz, and modified it to be as so: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-e2xenn?file=src%2Fsvg-circle.component.svg

Thanks goes to this medium article: https://medium.com/@danieltamirr/parameterized-angular-animations-fa73a2727158

In a nut shell we define a parameter value for our animation in our templat:

`[@animateStroke]="{ value: dashOffset, params: {timer: '1s linear'}}"`

Then inside of the actual component definition we can reference it as so:

```
style({
          'transition': '{{timer}}',
          'stroke-dashoffset': '*',

        }), { params: {timer: '1s linear'}}
```

Whereby the param value is just a default in case it is not provided from the template itself. Thus if say your template just had this for animate stroke:

`[@animateStroke]="dashOffset"`

it would then default to an animation speed of 1s linear, or whatever it is you want to define in that template

Comment: It seems like it ... Might work ... Are you able to modify the Stackblitz with an input value for the timing ... and pass it to the animation ... ?

Comment: Yes, it looks like you can. https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-e2xenn?file=src%2Fmain.template.html I added an input on one of the circles, whilst the other is left as is

Comment: WOW!!  Very cool!!  I'm so impressed!!  Thank you!!

Comment: No problem, I also learned something new today by doing this haha. Win- win